# How to replace/update scalar values in vtp file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vtk

I have a vtp file generated by OpenFOAM, a cfd solver. It contains the surface geometry of a body and the surface pressure values. Here's an example in ascii:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- time='0.02502' -->
<VTKFile type='PolyData' version='0.1' byte_order='LittleEndian' header_type='UInt64'>
  <PolyData>
    <FieldData>
      <DataArray type='Float32' Name='TimeValue' NumberOfTuples='1' format='ascii'>
0.245
      </DataArray>
    </FieldData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints='68554' NumberOfPolys='65952'>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type='Float32' Name='Points' NumberOfComponents='3' format='ascii'>
...
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Polys>
        <DataArray type='Int32' Name='connectivity' format='ascii'>
...
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type='Int32' Name='offsets' format='ascii'>
...
        </DataArray>
      </Polys>
      <PointData>
        <DataArray type='Float32' Name='p' format='ascii'>
...
        </DataArray>
      </PointData>
    </Piece>
  </PolyData>
</VTKFile>
```

I would like to replace/update the surface pressure values. How can I do it?

I tried to read the file to get the values and points in numpy arrays, then I tried to write a new vtp file using the original values and points as a check. I managed to write the vtp file but the surface pressure values are wrong and the new body has lots of jagged edges although the general shape is similar

My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jun 28 16:29:59 2023

@author: tsltaywb
"""

import vtk
import numpy as np
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk

# Read the VTP file
reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("input.vtp")
reader.Update()
polydata = reader.GetOutput()

# Access polygonal data
total_num_cells = polydata.GetNumberOfCells()
total_num_points = polydata.GetNumberOfPoints()
points_array = np.zeros((total_num_points,3))
cell_index_array = np.zeros((total_num_cells,5)) #need to test 1st max polygonal shape
cell_index = np.zeros((5))

coord_out = np.zeros((total_num_cells,5,3)) #need to test 1st max polygonal shape
cell_shape = np.zeros((total_num_cells))

tri_cells = 0
quad_cells = 0
polygon_cells = 0
hexa_cells = 0
other_cells = 0

point_id = 0

for cell_id in range(total_num_cells):
    
    cell = polydata.GetCell(cell_id)
    cell_type = cell.GetCellType()
    num_points = cell.GetNumberOfPoints()
    
    # Process polygonal data
    if cell_type == vtk.VTK_TRIANGLE:
        # Process triangle data
        point_ids = cell.GetPointIds()
        coord_out[cell_id,0] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
        coord_out[cell_id,1] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(1)))
        coord_out[cell_id,2] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(2)))
        # ... process triangle points
        tri_cells = tri_cells + 1
        
        cell_shape[cell_id] = 3
        
    elif cell_type == vtk.VTK_QUAD:
        # Process quad data
        point_ids = cell.GetPointIds()
        # coord_out[cell_id,0,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,1,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(1)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,2,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(2)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,3,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(3)))
        # ... process quad points
        
        quad_cells = quad_cells + 1
        
        cell_shape[cell_id] = 4
        
        #cell_index_array[cell_id,0:cell_shape[cell_id]] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(0:cell_shape[cell_id])
        
        cell_index_array[cell_id,0] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(0)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,1] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(1)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,2] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(2)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,3] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(3)
        
        for i in range(int(cell_shape[cell_id])):
        
            if int(cell_index_array[cell_id,i]) >= point_id:
            
                points_array[point_id,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
            
                point_id = point_id + 1
        
    elif cell_type == vtk.VTK_POLYGON:
        # Process quad data
        point_ids = cell.GetPointIds()
        # coord_out[cell_id,0,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,1,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(1)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,2,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(2)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,3,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(3)))
        # coord_out[cell_id,4,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(4)))
        
        polygon_cells = polygon_cells + 1
        
        cell_shape[cell_id] = 5
        
        #cell_index_array[cell_id,0:cell_shape[cell_id]] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(0:cell_shape[cell_id])
        
        cell_index_array[cell_id,0] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(0)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,1] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(1)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,2] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(2)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,3] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(3)
        cell_index_array[cell_id,4] = cell.GetPointIds().GetId(4)
        
        for i in range(int(cell_shape[cell_id])):
        
            if int(cell_index_array[cell_id,i]) >= point_id:
            
                points_array[point_id,:] = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
            
                point_id = point_id + 1
        
    elif cell_type == vtk.VTK_HEXAGON:
        # Process quad data
        point_ids = cell.GetPointIds()
        point_0 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(0)))
        point_1 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(1)))
        point_2 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(2)))
        point_3 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(3)))
        point_4 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(4)))
        point_5 = np.array(polydata.GetPoint(point_ids.GetId(5)))
        hexa_cells = hexa_cells + 1
    else:
        other_cells = other_cells + 1
  
print("tri_cells", tri_cells)
print("quad_cells", quad_cells)
print("polygon_cells", polygon_cells)
print("hexa_cells", hexa_cells)
print("other_cells", other_cells)

# Access scalar values
scalar_array = polydata.GetPointData().GetArray("p")
if scalar_array is not None:
    scalar_values = vtk_to_numpy(scalar_array)
    # ... process scalar values as a NumPy array

# Create the VTK polydata object
polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

points = vtk.vtkPoints()
for id in range(total_num_points):
    points.InsertPoint(id, points_array[id,:])
polydata.SetPoints(points)



polydata.Allocate(total_num_cells)
for id in range(total_num_cells):
    
    if cell_shape[id] == 4:
        
        point_ids = [int(cell_index_array[id,0]),int(cell_index_array[id,1]),int(cell_index_array[id,2]),int(cell_index_array[id,3])]
        
        polydata.InsertNextCell(vtk.VTK_QUAD, 4, point_ids)

    elif cell_shape[id] == 5:
        
        point_ids = [int(cell_index_array[id,0]),int(cell_index_array[id,1]),int(cell_index_array[id,2]),int(cell_index_array[id,3]),int(cell_index_array[id,4])]
        
        polydata.InsertNextCell(vtk.VTK_POLYGON, 5, point_ids)
        
number_of_components = 4

number_of_tuples = total_num_points

array = vtk.vtkDoubleArray()
array.SetNumberOfComponents(number_of_components)
array.SetNumberOfTuples(number_of_tuples)
array.SetName('p')
for id in range(number_of_tuples):
    values = [points_array[id,0],points_array[id,1],points_array[id,2],scalar_values[id]]
    array.SetTuple(id, values)
polydata.GetPointData().AddArray(array)

# Write the polydata to a VTP file
writer = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName("output.vtp")
writer.SetInputData(polydata)
writer.Write()
```

Can someone give a solution? I've been searching for answer but it seems that there's many ways to write vtk,vtp file. Thanks.